# Dropdown design not proper when dynamic options value added jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using admin theme : https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/

i'm using dropdown, i'm adding option to dropdown through jquery after ajax calls but after
loading the dropdown design gets disturbed.

I have re-initialized the dropdown

```
  $.each(data.categories,function(index,categories){
                jQuery('.list').append('<option value="'+index+'">'+categories+'</option>');
          });

   $(".list").selectpicker('refresh');
```

but it is not working.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Show us some code and describe what goes wrong.

Comment: @Grumpy: The issue is i cannot reinitialize the dropdown after adding values through ajax like the code i have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `.trigger('change')`

```
$(".list").selectpicker('refresh').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Why should he trigger change?

Comment: @MosiaThabo by definition, `.trigger()` executes all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type, thus correctly refreshes `selectpicker`.

Comment: Okay, I see. Cool! Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy: Thanks i have tried your code but the options are added outside the dropdown i have added screenshot above

Comment: @user3653474 try adding a `.selectpicker('render')` before the refresh. Also that's another problem - the original question of having them shown has been answered :-)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy: tried first time it is adding inside dropdown but when i change second time it renders options outside

Comment: @user3653474 personally I think this problem comes from the fact that you're using a class rather than an ID.

Comment: @user3653474 I would appreciate a +1 :-) I'm giving one back!